# Why can only my site collection administrators see modified master page(s)?

Tags: site-collection

I wanted to move the "Add new item button" to the top instead of the bottom of my lists and libraries.  I found a nice little script and applied it at the bottom, before the /body tag, of two master files: MyTeamSite.master and default.master (I wasn't sure which one to edit).

I checked the files in once I was done.  I looked at it on my browser and it showed up so I thought I was all set.  Well, it turns out that the only people that are seeing it are the ones set up as site collection administrators.  What gives?

The one thing I am noticing when I right click on the default.master is the option to "Set as Default Master Page".  Is this something that I should try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edits to the masterpages require content approval, so only administrators see pending changes. You need to navigate to the master page gallery, check in the file as a major version and approve it so all users will see the change.

Comment: Awesome, that did it and I approved it and now it looks like my other user can see it!